# What is the meaning of this expression?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

There's a discrete binary search article on topcoder where i met with this expression.

`while(lo & lt; hi )`
`if(i + j & lt ; = x )`

described below

I have never seen this expression ";" in a while loop and using & in it.

And Also, in general i want to know what `AND &` bit wise operator do(i know how it works in binary level but i wanted to know how the final result can be calculated without converted numbers into binary forms) and also the if statement in below code.

```
int getMostWork(vector folders, int workers) {
  int n = folders.size();
  int lo = * max_element(folders.begin(), folders.end());
  int hi = accumulate(folders.begin(), folders.end(), 0);

  while (lo & lt; hi) {
    int x = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

    int required = 1, current_load = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i & lt; n; ++i) {
      if (current_load + folders[i] & lt; = x) {
        // the current worker can handle it
        current_load += folders[i];
      } else {
        // assign next worker
        ++required;
        current_load = folders[i];
      }
    }

    if (required & lt; = workers)
      hi = x;
    else
      lo = x + 1;
  }

  return lo;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that these are just escaping issues with `&lt;` being the escaped text for `<` (less than)?

Comment: Yeah, bad HTML conversion  should be `i < n` and `lo < hi`

Comment: `while ( foo ; bar) ` is not valid syntax, look at the compiler errors: https://godbolt.org/z/LUVhso

Comment: You don't convert to binary. Binary is just a representation. 17, 0b10001, 0x11 and 021 are the same values. Bitwise operations are described with bits. Probably it's possible to describe these operations with other representations but it becomes more complex.

Comment: " the final result can be calculated without converted numbers into binary forms" too late. If numbers are in PC memory they are in binary forms already.

Comment: Almost any expression evaluates to a number or pointer, and if it is NULL/zero, then it evaluates to false, else true.  The semicolon is really odd, but in this context seems like, if it compiles, it would act like the comma, which executes, discards its rhs value, but does not count as a complete instruction for if, for, while body like a ; does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just bad formatting of the HTML for the "<" less than operator from wherever you found this code

The HTMLcode for `<` is `&lt;`

Replace all sequences of `&lt;` with `<` and you get:

```
    while (lo < hi) {
        int x = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

        int required = 1, current_load = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (current_load + folders[i] <= x) {
                // the current worker can handle it
                current_load += folders[i];
            }
            else {
                // assign next worker
                ++required;
                current_load = folders[i];
            }
        }

        if (required <= workers)
            hi = x;
        else
            lo = x + 1;
    }
```

No bitwise AND operator, just less than conditionals